# Tor website HPKP (key pinning) failure

Tags: man-in-the-middle, tor, hpkp

I'm currently facing a key pinning error when trying to access the torproject.org website with Firefox.

Is anyone facing the same problem? Does anyone know if they changed their certificate? If not, it may be a man-in-the-middle currently running.

Additional info : I get a *.opendns.com certificate Subject, signed by DigiCert Inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SN: 09:48:B1:A9:3B:25:1D:0D:B1:05:10:59:E2:C2:68:0A
SHA-256 Fingerprint: EA:16:D6:DA:76:9B:67:6B:C0:7A:19:A0:CD:21:AA:F1:5A:9A:66:93:A2:C3:CD:7A:87:81:7D:B1:6F:5F:48:F5

Nothing in the cert I am looking at has opendns in it.  IIRC OpenDNS does not support DNSSEC, they support DNScrypt-proxy which would not involve any cert being exposed to the browser.

Comment: Ok. thank you. I checked with another internet connection and I have the same SN as yours. It seems to be my provider that mitm the website with a valid ssl certificate. That's really awkward.